# How can I golf this JavaScript code, if at all?

Tags: tips, javascript

I have some JavaScript code in a `<script>` HTML tag I'd like to golf, while still remaining in the tag. How can I golf that code, if at all? Here's the code:

```
<script>document.write`<font color=#40e0d0 face=arial>YOU ARE IN THE BEDROOM.<br>YOU SEE CRAB NICHOLSON.<br>HE HAS NO MITTENS.<br>HIS CLAWS ARE MENACING.<br>OBVIOUS EXITS ARE:<br>BATHROOM, KITCHEN, LIVING ROOM<br>AND CRAB NICHOLSON'S<br>ULTIMATE LAIR OF AWESOMENESS</font>`;document.body.style.background="#000"</script>
```

Comment: Is these the complete HTML or just a part of it?

Answer (score 10):

Save 3 bytes by assigning `document` to a variable:

```
(d=document).write`<font color=#40e0d0 face=arial>YOU ARE IN THE BEDROOM.<br>YOU SEE CRAB NICHOLSON.<br>HE HAS NO MITTENS.<br>HIS CLAWS ARE MENACING.<br>OBVIOUS EXITS ARE:<br>BATHROOM, KITCHEN, LIVING ROOM<br>AND CRAB NICHOLSON'S<br>ULTIMATE LAIR OF AWESOMENESS</font>`;d.body.style.background="#000"
```

Save 2 bytes by reusing ' CRAB NICHOLSON':

```
(d=document).write(`<font color=#40e0d0 face=arial>YOU ARE IN THE BEDROOM.<br>YOU SEE${c=' CRAB NICHOLSON'}.<br>HE HAS NO MITTENS.<br>HIS CLAWS ARE MENACING.<br>OBVIOUS EXITS ARE:<br>BATHROOM, KITCHEN, LIVING ROOM<br>AND${c}'S<br>ULTIMATE LAIR OF AWESOMENESS</font>`);d.body.style.background="#000"
```

Save 1 byte by using `` .join`<br>` ``:

```
(d=document).write(`<font color=#40e0d0 face=arial>YOU ARE IN THE BEDROOM._YOU SEE${c=' CRAB NICHOLSON'}._HE HAS NO MITTENS._HIS CLAWS ARE MENACING._OBVIOUS EXITS ARE:_BATHROOM, KITCHEN, LIVING ROOM_AND${c}'S_ULTIMATE LAIR OF AWESOMENESS</font>`.split`_`.join`<br>`);d.body.style.background="#000"
```

Further golfs suggested by [@Night2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/464495?noredirect=1):

Save 14 bytes by using `.bgColor=0`:

```
(d=document).write(`<font color=#40e0d0 face=arial>YOU ARE IN THE BEDROOM._YOU SEE${c=' CRAB NICHOLSON'}._HE HAS NO MITTENS._HIS CLAWS ARE MENACING._OBVIOUS EXITS ARE:_BATHROOM, KITCHEN, LIVING ROOM_AND${c}'S_ULTIMATE LAIR OF AWESOMENESS</font>`.split`_`.join`<br>`);d.body.bgColor=0
```

Save 7 bytes by 'forgetting' to close the `<font>` tag (YMMV):

```
(d=document).write(`<font color=#40e0d0 face=arial>YOU ARE IN THE BEDROOM._YOU SEE${c=' CRAB NICHOLSON'}._HE HAS NO MITTENS._HIS CLAWS ARE MENACING._OBVIOUS EXITS ARE:_BATHROOM, KITCHEN, LIVING ROOM_AND${c}'S_ULTIMATE LAIR OF AWESOMENESS`.split`_`.join`<br>`);d.body.bgColor=0
```

Comment: You can save 1 byte by removing the `#` in the color. Google Chrome parses as the color `rgb(64, 224, 208)`, with or without the `#`.

Comment: OP did this help you? If so, please accept the answer